# StackOverflowError - how is it possible?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```js
package qwertyuiop;

public class Confusion {
    Confusion com = new Confusion();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Confusion con = new Confusion();
        System.out.println(4);
        con.A();
        System.out.println(5);
    }

    public void B() {
        System.out.println(3);
    }

    public void A() {
        System.out.println(4);
        com.B();
        System.out.println(4);
    }
}
```

I know the code is wrong but I am interested in knowing why this is throwing `StackOverflowError`. I would also like to know how this code is executing internally.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361

Comment: Give `Confusion` a constructor and make it print something.

Answer (score 3):

When you create `con`, the member of it(`com`) will be created. And when you try to create `com`, the member of it(another `com`) will be created. This procedure is repeated until stack overflow.

If you don't want to initiate `com` multiple times, you can make it a `static` member:

```
static Confusion com = new Confusion();
```

Comment: Depends on what OP intends to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with the basics (which you can skip if you already know about stack and heap):

The main memory for program execution is divided into basically two parts: stack and heap.

In programs, primitives and **references** to objects are stored in a **stack**, and the data of an object is stored in a heap, which is referenced by the reference stored in the stack.

Now everytime you use the new keyword, a new slot of memory from the heap is allocated to your object and it's address/reference is stored in the stack.

**READ FROM HERE IF YOU KNEW THAT**:

Coming to your problem, in your constructor, you call the constructor itself again, and this creates a recursive situation, in which the constructor calls itself again and again, thus the **new** is executed again and again and hence reference to more and more slots of heap are added to the stack until it runs out of memory.

Hence the exception.